# Extract first term of each element in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation

Suppose I have a list of the form

```
list={a+b,c+d,Xi+Psi*Zeta,0}
```

How can I make a list of only the first term of each element in that list? In this case the list would be just

```
list2={a,c,Xi,0}
```

Comment: I presume you are already aware that `c + a` is automatically converted to `a + c`?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, this is just a toy example

Comment: Mathematica consider `Xi` the "first" term in `Psi*Zeta+Xi` and not `Psi*Zeta`

Comment: @Nasser I edited it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In this case the list would be just list2={a,c,Xi,0}

For this example you show, this should it do it. But I do not know if this will fail or not for other examples. If you can provide more examples, it will help test it. These parsing things can be tricky depending on input

```
list = {a + b, c + d, Psi*Zeta + Xi, 0};
If[AtomQ[#], #, First[#]] & /@ list
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another example to handle  more general cases

```
list = {a + b, c + d, Psi*Zeta + Xi, 0, Exp[x], Sin[x], 
    x + Sin[x], 1 + Exp[x], x*Sin[x], Sin[x]^2, 1/x + 2, 
   {1, 2, 3}};

If[AtomQ[#] || Length[#] == 1 || Head[#] === Power || 
    Head[#] === List, #, First[#]] & /@ list
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. This might still fail on some other input. More example will help.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a case for the (often-overlooked) two-argument form of [`First`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html):

> [image]

```
list = {a + b, c + d, Psi*Zeta + Xi, 0};

First[#, #] & /@ list
```

> {a, c, Xi, 0}

Second example from Nasser's answer with exceptions can be handled using:

```
listb = {a + b, c + d, Psi*Zeta + Xi, 0, Exp[x], Sin[x], x + Sin[x], 
   1 + Exp[x], x*Sin[x], Sin[x]^2, 1/x + 2, {1, 2, 3}};

listb /. $pat : Except[_Power | _List | _?(Length @ # == 1 &)] :> First[$pat, $pat]
```

[image]